# How to get unique visitors IP using a hit counter and prevent count spam

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a hit counter for every unique visitor. But I can't figure out how to get every users unique IP address and at the same time prevent that user from refreshing the page 100 times and spamming my hit counter table.

Every page has a unique alias that I get using $_GET['alias']

I get the hits from this query:

```
$click  = "SELECT hits FROM snm_content WHERE alias = '".$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['alias'])."'";
```

Every time a user visits a page, I want the hit counter that has the same alias as the page visited to add 1. And check for spam.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can not rely on IP to distinguish visitor
An Entreprise will have a unique IP Public address with 1000 employees, you will consider all of them as a unique user ?

Comment: Do you want to count each user for individual page or for all the pages? So if user with ip x access page1 and page2 do you want to count 2 times or only once?

Comment: Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Yeah I am aware @Techie I'll update the original post. Alright Halayem Anis, so what do you think is the best way?

Comment: @DanielDudas For each page, I got one content.php that has a dynamic alias, the hit only needs to add 1 in the table with the same alias as the page visited.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using the IP address to identify your visitors?

If not, you could use a cookie which is set the first time a user visits your website.

From that time on you could check on each page if a user has your cookie (if not, set it) and then check if the pc with that cookie has been on that page already. That's the easiest solution I could think up.

Comment: So I have to save the cookie value or session value in a database? To compare it.

Comment: Yep! That wat you check every pc instead of IP, which could be more than one pc.